# Problemas ao centralizar slideshow

Tags: css

Quero centralizar meu *slideshow*, só que quando coloco o style `margin: 0 auto` não centraliza e acontece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    width:100%;
    max-width:980px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.slide {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}

.slide-1 {
    width:75%;
    height:505px;
    float:left;
}

.slide-2 {
    width:25%;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
}

.slide-3 {
    width:25%;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
}

.slide-1 img {
    width:700px;
    height:500px;
}

.slide-2 img {
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
    margin-left:-35px;
}

.slide-3 img {
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
    margin-left:-35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar isso:

```
.slideshow {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    max-width:980px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: não funcionou !

Comment: bom, o meu código do .container é esse: {max-width: 960px; width: 100%; height: auto; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; z-index: 10} o seu está igual... posta a estrutura do seu html ai

Comment: <div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slide">

    <div class="slide-1">
     <img src="img/01.jpg">
    </div>
        
    <div class="slide-2">
     <img src="img/img02.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-3">
     <img src="img/img02.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>